# How to replace nulls in entire sheet without knowing which column will have null values

Tags: sql, ms-access

Several times a month I append data from excel to our database using Microsoft Access. Right now I have update queries that look for nulls in columns that commonly have them and replaces them with empty strings.

```
 UPDATE example_excel_sheet SET example_excel_sheet.trouble_column_1 = '', 
 example_excel_sheet.trouble_column_2 = '', example_excel_sheet.trouble_column_3 = '', 
 WHERE (((example_excel_sheet.trouble_column_1)='' Or (example_excel_sheet.trouble_column_1) 
 Is Null) AND ((example_excel_sheet.trouble_column_2)='' Or (example_excel_sheet.trouble_column_2) Is 
 Null) AND ((example_excel_sheet.trouble_column_3)='' Or 
 (example_excel_sheet.trouble_column_3) Is Null));
```

There are 2 problems with this solution

1. This query only updates if all three trouble columns are either null or blank
2. The columns that might be null are sometimes unpredictable, there might be 5 null fields instead of 3 so I'll have to do the extra 2 manually.

Please tell me there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you even want empty strings in table? I NEVER allow empty strings.

Comment: I don't know why nulls would be preferable? But the MySQL table I'm appending to doesn't allow nulls.

Comment: I suppose it is mostly personal preference and training. Consistency may be the key. It is very annoying if code is designed to expect only one or the other and data contains unexpected one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use Nz() then it is irrelevant if field is Null or not. Eliminate WHERE clause and run update on every record. Include all columns that might need update.

`UPDATE example_excel_sheet SET trouble_column_1 = Nz(trouble_column_1,''),  trouble_column_2 = Nz(trouble_column_2),''), trouble_column_3 = Nz(trouble_column_3),''), trouble_column_4 = Nz(trouble_column_4),''), trouble_column_5 = Nz(trouble_column_5),'')`

Or to avoid calling that VBA function use IIf and IS NULL

`trouble_column_1 = IIf(trouble_column_1 IS NULL, '', trouble_column_1)`

Or use VBA and run 5 separate SQL action statements.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Should save me a whole bunch of time and headache.